# checking if some vectors span $\Bbb R^3$ that actualy span $\Bbb R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If we want to check if the following set of vector span $\Bbb R^3$: $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,-1)$, $(0,4,-3)$, $(0,2,0)$ then we forme an augmented matrix formed by the vectors which form the columns of the augmented matrix and add and extra vector $u=(u_1,u_2,u_3)$.

Solving this augmented matrix give me the following solution

$C_1=u_1;
C_2=6c_4-3u_2-4u_3;
C_3=-2c_4+u_2+u_3$

Therefore we got many solutions to the augmented matrix ,and that is expected given we got more unknows than equations.

However what does this mean for the span?

I know that this actually span $\Bbb R^3$ but how do i conclued that?

Edit: forming an equation to see that if every vector from $\Bbb R^3$ can be written as a combination of the of vector above give the following equation

$c_1(1,0,0)+c_2(0,1,-1)+c_3(0,4,-3)+c_4(0,2,0)= (u_1,u_2,u_3)$

Making the left side as an unique vector ,and then relating the components of each side then forme a coefficient matrix of it and then do following type $\boldsymbol Ac=u$.

The augmented matix is the following matix

$$\left[\begin{array}{r,r,r,r|r}1&0&0&0&u_1\\0&1&4&2&u_2\\0&-1&-3&0&u_3\end{array}\right]$$

Now solving this matrix to reduce row-echelon give the result above i add also here

$C_1=u_1;
C_2=6c_4-3u_2-4u_3;
C_3=-2c_4+u_2+u_3$

Getting to this point i know.so what implication does it have on the span,how do we imply that the set of vectors span $\Bbb R^3$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i realize that we could rearrange the solution and form 3 equations and solve for each u and that tells us that we got any solution for each u as the oposite if we got a constant then we know that no matter what vector we pick fromthe span it wouldnt span all R3

Answer (score 2):

What you would do is to take the determinant of a $3\times 3$ matrix whose columns are the vectors that you conjecture to be independent (thus they span $\mathbb R^3$). Notice that since you have $4$ of these vectors you select three. The procedure is to take the determinant. If it is different from $0$ then the $3$ vectors you selected are independent and they span $\mathbb R^3$. If the $\det$ is $0$ select other $3$ vectors... If all of the combinations of vectors that form a $3\times 3$ matrix have determinant $0$, then the vectors are dependent and they don't span $\mathbb R^3$. If any of these matrices formed by putting $3$ vectors as its columns has determinant different from $0$, then the other vector can be written as a combination of the three independent vectors you've found.

For instance:

$$\det\left[\begin{array}{r,r,r}1&0&0\\0&1&4\\0&-1&-3\end{array}\right]=-3+4=1\neq0.$$

Therefore the first three vectors you mentioned are independent and span $\mathbb R^3$.

Moreover, we know that if there are constants $k_1,k_2,k_3,k_4$, at least one of them different from $0$, such that for every $c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4\in\mathbb R$ (these come from the vector solution $\mathbf c$) we have that (if we name the columns $C_1,C_2,C_3,C_4$) $k_1C_1+k_2C_2+k_3C_3+k_4C_4=\boldsymbol0$, then the columns are dependent.

So let's assume that the columns are dependent and we will try to reach a contradiction. If $k_1\neq 0$ the contradiction is trivial since the first column of your matrix is $\left[\begin{array}{c}1\\0\\0\end{array}\right]\Longrightarrow k_1c_1\left[\begin{array}{c}1\\0\\0\end{array}\right]+\boldsymbol \xi\neq \left[\begin{array}{c}0\\0\\0\end{array}\right]\text{for some } c_1\in\mathbb R.$ The same happens if we select $k_4\neq0$. So the thing turns interesting when $k_1,k_4=0$. Then we are left with the two columns of the middle. Of course if additionally $k_2=0$ or $k_3=0$ then the contradiction is trivial as well. But if $k_2,k_3\neq 0$, then we have the system:
\begin{align}
c_2+4c_3=u_2, && -c_2-3c_3=u_3.
\end{align}
$\text{That yields } c_3=u_2+u_3.$ Therefore $c_3$ does not depend on $c_2$ and it is impossible that $k_2(c_2+4c_3)+k_3(-c_2-3c_3)=0,\,\forall c_2,c_3\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: Ok.i understood,thank you also, but what about following the procedure that i refer in the post ,form a equation then an augmented matrix ,...what it happens in this case?or in fact is impossible to determine that way

Comment: @KellyBlunie I've never seen that procedure. If you could write the matrix that you refer to I would take a look at it, I'm not understanding how to form the matrix you propose.

Comment: Ok i am going to try that on the post

Comment: Sorry for delay i just edit the post can you check it

Comment: So what do you think about the procedure and question in the post

Comment: @KellyBlunie. I edited my post to answer your question.

Comment: I read it your post some times but i can figure out what is vector solution c, and what are the columns $C_i$.can you explicitly show what it is, becuase i do not quite follow your conclusion

Comment: @KellyBlunie The columns are the four vectors. And $\mathbf c$ is the solution of $\mathbf{Ac}=\mathbf u$.

Comment: I don`t understand everything that you said,its a litle confusing to me for example how do you relate the solutions from the augmented matrix with the columns vectors of that matrix( or just the vectors that form colums C_i).also dont see what it is the conclution of it and relation with span

Comment: And also what is the equations stating.linear indepence?

Comment: Note that i understand the first part of your anwser

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19439/discussion-between-notstrang-and-kelly-blunie).